# Can't get Postgres table partitoning to work

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm running postgres 9.5.7 on windows.

I'm trying to create a partitioned table using...

```
CREATE TABLE processlog2
(
  processlogid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 
  nextval('processlog_processlogid_seq'::regclass),
  starttime timestamp without time zone,
  endtime timestamp without time zone,
  durationsecs integer,
  processname character(100),
  itemcount integer,
  comment character(255),
  params character varying(20)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (starttime );
```

And I get the error...

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PARTITION"
LINE 12: PARTITION BY RANGE (starttime );
```

I think Postgres has supported partitioning for years, but I can't find any mention of this error and aren't sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131797/why-cannot-create-partitioning-table, but no one's written up an answer yet.

Comment: @melpomene Good spot, I've moved my answer there; I can't vote this as a duplicate until someone upvotes it though. For avoidance of doubt: the manual page seems identical for 9.5 and 9.6, so the instructions are valid for both questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why cannot create partitioning table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131797/why-cannot-create-partitioning-table)